# puppeteer - export JSON file from loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, web-scraping, puppeteer

The exported file contains only one url. The rest of the urls are not found in the exported file. How can I generate a file with all the entries in the loop?

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require('fs');

let browser;
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: ['--no-sandbox']
});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto('https://old.reddit.com/',{"waitUntil" : "networkidle0"});
  const a_elems = await page.$$('.thumbnail');

  for (var i=0; i<a_elems.length && i<3; i++) {            
     const elem = a_elems[i];
     const href = await page.evaluate(e => e.href, elem); 
     const newPage = await browser.newPage();
     await newPage.goto(href,{"waitUntil" : "networkidle0"});
     
        const url = await newPage.evaluate(() => document.location.href);
        console.log(url);

        fs.writeFileSync('export.json', JSON.stringify(url));
    }

    await browser.close();
})()
;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array, push each `url` onto it in the loop, then move your `writeFile` call to the end.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require('fs').promises;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: ['--no-sandbox']
  });
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto('https://old.reddit.com/', {
    "waitUntil": "networkidle0"
  });
  const aElems = await page.$$('.thumbnail');
  const urls = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < aElems.length && i < 3; i++) {
    const href = await aElems[i].evaluate(e => e.href);
    const newPage = await browser.newPage();
    await newPage.goto(href, {waitUntil: "networkidle0"});

    const url = await newPage.evaluate(() => document.location.href);
    console.log(url);
    urls.push(url);
  }

  await fs.writeFile('export.json', JSON.stringify(urls));
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

Tips:

- You're already in async code, so `writeFileSync` seems suboptimal here relative to the async version.
- Use `let` instead of `var` so you don't get bit by `i` breaking scope and popping up with a stale value outside (or inside) the loop block.
- Consider `newPage.close();` at the end of the loop. You're only doing 3 pages now, but if this is temporary and you're going to make it 800, then it's a great idea.
- `"waitUntil": "networkidle0"` is really slow. Since all you're doing is accessing `document.location.href` you can probably speed things up with `waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"`.
- JS uses `camelCase`, not `snake_case`.
- If you have an ElementHandle, you can just `elementHandle.evaluate(...)` rather than `page.evaluate(..., elementHandle)`.
- Catch errors with `catch` and clean up the `browser` resource with `finally`.
- `let browser;` was pointless in your original code.